# Retrieving Data into a Table Depending on Time?

Tags: mysql

I'm building an 'events' table that will show the events for that particular day.
However, since most events start late in the evening and end early in the morning I would like to know as to how I should plot and retrieve the data. Let's say that and *event day* starts at 6:01 AM and ends at 6:00 AM. Is the time dependent on the server time? Can I change it to some other GMT time? How would the time table look in the mysql database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a table like this:

```
Event
======
EventID
Name
StartTime 
EndTime
```

`StartTime` and `EndTime` would be stored as UTC dates. With this schema you can query however you like, and present the time for whatever time zone you like, but it keeps things consistent and well performing. You would want to index `EventID`, `StartTime`, and `EndTime`.